# Read an Excel file in R and extract specific color cells

Tags: r, excel

I would like to load an Excel file with multiple sheets into R and extract specific cell information.
The cell information is in the form of a string.
The specific cells are the shaded cells.

The following is a link to a sample Excel file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HTRb2MCt1PtAmcC8uwhGkt653jT-vyA4/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107958392552603639319&rtpof=true&sd=true

In the sample file, there are three sheets. Each is shaded in yellow.
Binder
19.99
63.68
I want to extract the data and store it in a variable as data.frame type.

If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: I get a message that I do not have permission to open the file

Comment: I am not sure to understand if you want to retreive the information about the color of the cell or the actual content of the cell that has a specific color.

Comment: Maybe you will find this usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982344/using-r-to-read-out-excel-colorinfo/43563918. I guess you can use it to extract info about cell colors and use it to get "coordinates" of the cells you want to select.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Categorise coloured cells using \`readxl\` package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209686/categorise-coloured-cells-using-readxl-package)

Comment: @maarvd excuse me. Would you please check the file again? You can probably browse it.

Comment: @Paul Rather than getting the cell color information, I want to get the information contained in a cell of a particular color.

Comment: still not authorized to access the file.